# Android: get the integer value from a byte

Tags: int, byte

I'm recording some audio in an Android app, and now I want to know that's the samples' value I'm getting. Since the record is in bytes, I would like to convert it to int or floats, to compare signal levels easier.

I'm trying to do so with this script, but it doesn't work:

```
                    byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];

                    read = recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);

                    int dataInt[]= new int[bufferSize];//To convert into int

                    for (int j=0; j<bufferSize ; j++)
                    {
                        dataInt[j]=data[j].intValue();

                    }
```

Could anyone tell me what am I doint wrong?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why is it easier to use integers instead of bytes?

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera I'm writting the information in a file that I'm planning to analice later, and bytes are just weird symbols I can't analice. With integers at least I have some values that I guess would deppend on the frequency or in the intentisty of the sound.

Comment: @Thilo Nop, that's the problem, on line: dataInt[j]=data[j].intValue();
I get the error: Cannot invoke intValue() on the primitive type byte

Comment: You definitely can analyze binary files. You just need a binary viewer. What you want to do is actually write your stream as a numeric _text_ representation into a file, right?

Comment: Yes, so I'm at the moment trying to do it with buffereWriter.write(Integer.toString(dataint[x])); 
Don't know if there is a faster way, but maybe this can works. Thank for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling intValue() on a primitive byte value! Why can't you just do

```
dataInt[j]=data[j];
```